# Can you "jam" a port?

Tags: networking

I have a probably simple question for most people.

To make my question easier i will call one person Client 1 and Client 2.

If for example Client 1 is downloading content through for example port 80 and Client 2 comes along and tries to download through port 80 too. Would that mean Client 2 has to wait for Client 1 to finish?

Comment: No. This would be horrible. Google, Facebook, StackOverflow, Netflix, ... could only serve one person at a time... What a cruel world that would be.

Comment: So there is not like they split up 100 bytes and sends 1 and 1 to the people connecting to the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OS reserves each incoming/outgoing port and ip combination. Every reserved port is "jammed", only one application can listen on a port at a time.

This goes for port 80 as well. If client 1 connects to port 80 TCP and goes to download something, that port is reserved and client 2 has to wait, unless the port was reserved with an ip as well (as is tradition).